# Why Server Vector Tiles for MapboxGL Client rendered incorrectly

Tags: postgis, vector-tiles, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to set up a web server in Node.js that serves vector tiles to be displayed in a browser using MapboxGL JS. The data for the vector tiles is stored in a PostGIS database.

I receive a geojson file and process it createing a database with next sentence:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS countries (
  table_id SERIAL,
  properties jsonb not null,
  geom geometry(GeometryZ,4326),
  primary key (table_id)
);
```

My current set up seems to going in the right direction, as I can see vector tiles being loaded and displayed in the browser. However the rendered result is incorrect (this is a screenshot of a section of my map):

[image]

What is rendering incorrectly???

Here is the code:

```
var express = require('express');
var SphericalMercator = require('sphericalmercator');
var mercator = new SphericalMercator({
    size: 256 //tile size
});

const { pool } = require('../postgressql/config');

var app = express();

app.get('/:namelayer/:z/:x/:y.pbf', (req, res, next) => {
    var options = {
        x: parseInt(req.params.x),
        y: parseInt(req.params.y),
        z: parseInt(req.params.z),
        layerName: req.params.namelayer
    };
    const bbox = mercator.bbox(options.x, options.y, options.z, false, '3857');
    const sql = `
        SELECT ST_AsMVT(q, '${options.layerName}', 4096, 'geom')
        FROM (
            SELECT
                table_id, properties,
                ST_AsMVTGeom(
                    geom,
                    ST_MakeEnvelope(${bbox[0]}, ${bbox[1]}, ${bbox[2]}, ${bbox[3]}, 4326),
                    4096,
                    256,
                    false
                ) AS geom
            FROM ${'public.'+options.layerName} c
        ) q;
    `;

    try {
        pool.query(sql, (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    ok: false,
                    message: error
                });
            }

            const tile = results.rows[0];
            // set the response header content type
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-protobuf');

            // trigger catch if the vector tile has no data, (return a 204)
            if (tile.st_asmvt.length === 0) {
                res.status(204);
            }  

            // send the tile!
            res.send(tile.st_asmvt);
        });
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(404).send({
            error: e.toString(),
        });
    }
});


module.exports = app;
```

I followed using the idea from this sites:

- https://medium.com/nyc-planning-digital/using-the-new-mvt-function-in-postgis-75f8addc1d68
- https://geoinquiets.github.io/taller-vt/8_postgis_vt/
- https://blog.jawg.io/how-to-make-mvt-with-postgis/